# How to access file present in network shared drive with credentials in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have NiFi instance 1.3.0 running on my local Windows. I want to copy a file from a one network drive to HDFS.

I think getFile processor reads files inside share directory

//server/shared/path/to/file.

Normally my shared drive prompts for credentials before access folder.

I tried getFile processor for access shared drive without credentials it worked.

But it not worked if credentials asked for network drive.

Can anyone suggest way to access network drive folder with credentials and move it into HDFS using NiFi processors?

Comment: you should give access to the file system (no matter if it local or remote) to the OS user. and if you run nifi under this user then it will have direct access to file system without any additional credentials.

Comment: credentials different from my username and i wants to access files from nifi processors only.

Comment: so create a technical user and run nifi under this user and give access to file system to this technical user. also read the following guide https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/26089/windows-share-nifi-hdfs-a-practical-guide.html

Comment: No i do not configure that Nifi to run as per technical user